# how to move an object in java with arrow keys using appletviewer

Tags: java

i am learning java and i was trying to create a small game application using 
java awt... here's my code ..it is not complete though.. i am not able to move the rocket to the left or right using the left or 
right navigation keys by using keylistener...
can you please help me figure out what the mistake is

```
import java.applet.*;
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.*;

/* <applet code="demo" height =1000 width =1000></applet>*/

public class demo extends Applet implements Runnable,KeyListener
{

    int b=10;
    int keypressX=0;

    int min=60,max=940,min1=10,max1=300;
    double[] x= new double[10];
    double[] y=new double[10];
    Thread t=null;
    public void init()
    {

        setBackground(Color.black);
        t= new Thread(this,"First");
        t.start();


    }
    public void run()
    {

        for( ; ; )
        {

            for(int k=0;k<10;k++){

            x[k] = Math.random()*((max-min)+1)+min;
            y[k] = Math.random()*((max1-min1)+1)+min1;


            }

            while(b<=500)
            {
                try{
                Thread.sleep(250);

                b+=10;

                repaint();}
                catch(Exception e){}
            }
            b=10;
        }


    }

    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent ke){
        int key=ke.getKeyCode();
        if(key== KeyEvent.VK_LEFT){
            keypressX=-10;

        }
        if(key == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT){
            keypressX=10;

        }
        repaint();

    }
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent ke){}
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent ke){}

    public void paint(Graphics g){


        for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
        {
            g.setColor(Color.white);
            g.fillOval((int)x[i],(int)y[i]+b,30,30);
        }



        g.setColor(Color.gray);
        g.fillRect(480+keypressX,800,40,100);
        g.setColor(Color.blue);
        g.fillRect(460+keypressX,825,20,50);
        g.fillRect(520+keypressX,825,20,50);
        g.setColor(Color.yellow);
        g.fillRect(490+keypressX,830,20,50);
        int xpts[]={480+keypressX,500+keypressX,520+keypressX};
        int ypts[]={800,750,800};
        g.setColor(Color.blue);
        g.fillPolygon(xpts,ypts,3);



        int xpt[]={480+keypressX,520+keypressX,510+keypressX,490+keypressX};
        int ypt[]={950,950,900,900};
        g.setColor(Color.blue);
        g.fillPolygon(xpt,ypt,4);
    }
}
```

Comment: which object you want to move

Comment: In `keyPressed()` just change `keypressX -= 10;` and `keypressX += 10;` respectively for left and right arrow keys

Comment: @DigvijaysinhGohil were right, i want to add something add KeyListener to the class also